# How to fix Theano crash caused by missing blas config?

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, openblas

When I try to use Theano, I run into the following error:

```
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'blas'
```

([full log](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/807278ed53c64979f1da2468fca4a394))

The following minimal example reproduces the problem:

```
FROM python:3.9.9-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev g++ libopenblas-dev libopenblas-base libatlas-base-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev

RUN pip install theano

RUN python -c "from theano import *"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Same error, anyone figure how to fix?